# Is there a way to protect my POST routes in my express.js app?

Tags: javascript, html, express, web

Is there any way possible that someone may know of to protect POST routes? I want to use fetch in my client side code, and make it so that the only code who can access my server post routes is my client code.

Currently, I am using CORS Middleware and also using the Host, Origin, and Referer headers, although they can be changed.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/csurf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, the client is under the control of the user; you can make it more annoying, but you can never make it impossible or even difficult.